# Divide string into two parts based on separator in Scala

Tags: scala

input:

myString = ""FILTER=(ID=123,Description=456)""

output:

FILTER, (ID=123,Description=456)

basically divide the string into two parts
How can i achieve this ?

Want something equivalent to [str.partition(sep)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) as in python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `split` with a `limit` parameter (but you don't get the separator as an element as in the Python `partition`)

```
val myString = "FILTER=(ID=123,Description=456)"     
myString.split("=", 2)  
//> res0: Array[String] = Array(FILTER, (ID=123,Description=456))
```

It's actually a java method - see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

The `span`-method could also be helpful for you

```
   val myString = "FILTER=(ID=123,Description=456)"
   //myString: String = FILTER=(ID=123,Description=456)

   myString.span(_!='=')
   //res9: (String, String) = (FILTER,=(ID=123,Description=456))
```

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP stated (it leaves an extra separator at the start of the second string)